# How to keep indexes/values after deleting them in r

Tags: r

is it possible to keep values and their index after deleting them ? 
I mean i'm intresting in testing some interpolation methods and I would like to delete some values, run my interpolation and compare the new values created with those I deleted before. So I don't have problems to delete randomly some values but  I don't know how to proceed to keep them. I hope that my question was clear,

Best regards,

Maxime

Comment: Why delete them in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: If I interpolate, I can't compare with previous values because the methods fit with all the points so I need to delete some and keep them. After this I interpolate and compare with the previous values that I stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best answer to this question is one that challenges its premise: You don't have to delete your interpolated values to do another form of interpolation. An example:

```r
xvals <- 1:10 # These are the observed x values
yvals <- sin(xvals) # The observed y values
linear_interpolation <- approx(xvals, yvals) # linear interpolation of values
spline_interpolation <- spline(xvals, yvals, n = 50) # spline interpolation
# We can collect the interpolation results in a dataframe for easy comparison
comparison <- data.frame(x = linear_interpolation$x,
                         linear_interpolation = linear_interpolation$y,
                         spline_interpolation = spline_interpolation$y)
head(comparison) # Look at the first few rows
#>          x linear_interpolation spline_interpolation
#> 1 1.000000            0.8414710            0.8414710
#> 2 1.183673            0.8539289            0.9476460
#> 3 1.367347            0.8663868            1.0066238
#> 4 1.551020            0.8788447            1.0227805
#> 5 1.734694            0.8913027            1.0004924
#> 6 1.918367            0.9037606            0.9441358
# We can also plot them to compare visually
# I like to use the colorblind-friendly palette from
# Wong, Bang. 2011. "Points of view: Color blindness." Nature Methods 8:441.
wong_palette <- c("#e69f00", "#56b4e9", "#009e73")
# Start with the observed values
plot(xvals, yvals, pch = 19, xlab = "X Values", ylab = "Y Values",
     main = "Interpolation Comparison")
# Plot the linear interpolation
lines(linear_interpolation, col = wong_palette[1])
# The spline interpolation
lines(spline_interpolation, col = wong_palette[2])
# And, since we know the true function in this simulation, the true function
lines(linear_interpolation$x, sin(linear_interpolation$x), col = wong_palette[3])
# Finish with a legend so we know what we're looking at
legend("bottomleft", seg.len = 1, lty = 1, bty = "n", col = wong_palette,
       legend = c("Linear Interp.", "Spline Interp.", "True Function"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I don't want to delete interpolated values but I want to compare numericaly two types of interpolation. So I want to delete real values, interpolate and then compare the difference between the real value (that I deleted and stored before) and the value computed by interpolation (in this case I use Spline and Approx). In that way i'm able to perform a RMSE for example.

Comment: @MaximeTroiani No problem! If it helped you solve your issue, don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Finally I did like this (not very conventionalbut...) :

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did like this (not very conventional but..) :

## Create a data frame

`data_test<-data.frame(
  x<-1:10,
  y<-1:10
)
data_test`

## replace randomy some values by NA

`data_test$y [sample(nrow(data_test),2)]<- NA
data_test`

## find the index with those NA

`index<-which(data_test$y %in% c(NA))
index`

## keeping these deleted values

`store_data<-data_test[index,]`

## deleting values with NA in the df

`data_testnew<- na.omit(data_test)
data_testnew`